# The right time to destroy an interstitial ad

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, interstitial

When is it the right time to destroy an interstitial ad in Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin?

The docs say:"It is important to explicitly destroy the interstitial **before letting it go out of scope** so that it can be properly released by the plugin."

Should the interstitial ad be destroyed right after it shows? when it is clicked? or when about to be closed?

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: answer: before it goes out of scope. As long as you do in fact destroy it, it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you're handling the ad. If the reference to the ad is a member of a monobehaviour class, you could call ad.Destroy() on the script's OnDestroy. If it's a local variable inside some method, then you have to call ad.Destroy() before leaving the method.

Comment: Thanks user2599140, yes the reference to the ad is a class member variable.I guess I will just add the OnDestroy() function and then destroy the ad within it.